# A question about the calculation of an integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Compute the integral $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos(nx) - \cos(mx)}{x} dx$ for n,m are positive real numbers and $n<m$.

I am thinking about the following:

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos(nx) - \cos(mx)}{x} dx = & \int_0^{\infty} \int_n^{m} \sin(xy) dy dx \nonumber\\
= & \int_n^{m} \int_0^{\infty} \sin(xy) dx dy \nonumber\\
= & \int_n^{m} [- \cos(xy)/y ]|_0^{\infty} dy \nonumber\\
\end{eqnarray}

but the integrand of the $3rd$ integral doesn't converge.  What is wrong in my solution?

Comment: is it possible to switch the integrals in your question? is it a non-negative function ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to see with the modulus, but we have

$$\int_0^\infty \int_n^m |\sin(xy)| \,dy dx \geqslant \int_0^\infty \int_n^m {\big(\sin(xy)\big)}^2 \,dy dx$$

and this last integral can be more easily computed in terms of the [sine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html).
Indeed,

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \int_n^m {\big(\sin(xy)\big)}^2 \,dy dx
&= \int_0^\infty \left [\frac y2 -\frac{\sin(2xy)}{4x}\right]^m_n \,dx
\\&=
\int_0^\infty \frac {m-n}2 +\frac{\sin(2nx) - \sin(2mx)}{4x} \,dx
\\&=
\left[ \frac {(m-n)x}2 \right]_0^\infty + \frac14\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(2nx)}x\,dx
- \frac14\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(2mx)}x\,dx
\end{align}

Now, with $k>0$ and $u = kx$ we get

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(kx)}x \, dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(u)}{\frac uk} \, \frac1k du = \int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(u)}u\,du = \lim_{t\to\infty} \text{Si}(t)=\pi/2,$$

and hence $\int_0^\infty \int_n^m {\big(\sin(xy)\big)}^2 \,dy dx = +\infty$.
It follows that we may not apply Fubini's Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at: [Frullani's integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral).

Comment: Basically, I'd like to know if I can get an answer using my way. Also, the limit of $f(x)$ doesn't exist when $x$ approaches $\infty$ so I can't use the theorem.

Comment: You can apply other versions of the theorem in the [linked source](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1990-109-01/S0002-9939-1990-1007485-4/S0002-9939-1990-1007485-4.pdf).